# C++ Usage of AsyncCallback

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a method, for example:

```
void Something::DoSomething(double d1, double d2, void* callback)
{
  AsyncCallback^ acb = gcnew AsyncCallback(this, System::IntPtr(callback)); //error C3364: 'System::AsyncCallback' : invalid argument for delegate constructor; delegate target needs to be a pointer to a member function 
  sensor->BeginSearch(d1, d2, acb);
}
```

How can I get this to work?

This method shell be exported and will be used by a native c++ app.

**EDIT:**

After some searching my current progress is the following:

.h

```
typedef std::tr1::function<void(void)>* callback_function;
ref class Something
{
  public:
  void DoSomething(double d1, double d2, callback_function callback);
  void DoSomethingCallback (IAsyncResult^ ar);

  private:
  callback_function m_callback;
}
```

.cpp

```
void Something::DoSomething(double d1, double d2, callback_function callback)
{
  m_callback = callback;
  AsyncCallback^ acb = gcnew AsyncCallback(this, &Something::DoSomethingCallback);
  sensor->BeginSearch(d1, d2, acb);
}
void Something::DoSomethingCallback(IAsyncResult^ ar)
{
  (*m_callback());
}
```

Usage in native code:

h.

```
class NativeClass
{
  public:
  void NativeFunction(double d1, double d2);

  std::tr1::function<void()> m_callback;
}
```

.cpp

```
void NativeClass::NativeFunction(double d1, double d2)
{
  m_callback = std::tr1::bind(&SomethingElse::DoSomethingCallback, this);
  sensor->DoSomething(d1, d2, &m_callback);
}

void SomethingElse::DoSomethingCallback(void)
{
  // Does something
}
```

Now it seems to work. The only problem I am facing right now is, that my managed code throws the following exception somwhere at `(*m_callback())` the program stopps in a class called `xxfunction`:

```
An unhandled exception of type System.AccessViolationException occurred in .dll  Additional information: An attempt was made to read or write in the protected memory. This is an indication that other memory is corrupted.
```

Comment: @HansPassant is it possible for you to provide an example? It's hard for me to follow. 

I will update my question with what I currently have.

Comment: Your title says "with non-member function", but your actual code makes a pointer-to-member-function, right on the like where the error is.  This has nothing to do with C++/CLI; your native C++ bits have a type mismatch.

Comment: @BenVoigt I initialy tried something else. Well, now I ended up beeing here. Sorry for that confusion. 
"your native C++ bits have a type mismatch" I don't get this line. I mean, clearly there is a mismatch, just like the error mentioned, but I don't know how to fix that :(

Answer (score 0):

`&SomethingElse::DoSomethingCallback` is the address of a member-function.

`typedef void (*callback_function)(void);` is a pointer to a non-member function.

The two are not compatible.

You probably wanted `std::function<void(void)>`, but you can't put that directly inside a managed type, so you end up with

```
typedef std::function<void(void)>* callback_function;
```

which will be called as

```
(*m_callback)(); // works for pointer to std::function, and also the most correct syntax for a plain function pointer
```

And then your `ref class Something` needs copy-constructor, copy-assignment, and destructor, to properly free the native object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! For the destructor, I used a virtual destructor and did this inside it: `delete m_callback` . What do I have to do in the copy- and assignment constructor?

Comment: @Anon: Try `m_callback = new std::tr1::function<void(void)>(cb);`

Comment: @Anon: Well, you're storing a pointer to a local variable.  When that local goes out of scope, the pointer becomes worthless.  Try my suggestion.

Comment: `m_callback` (usage in native code) is a variable of a class, it is not local. What exact suggestion of yours do you mean?

Comment: @Anon: Using dynamic allocation (`new`) to make a copy of the std::function that lives until you free it.  At the moment you have *two* variables named `m_callback`.  One inside the class, and one `m_callback = std::tr1::bind(...)` which you take the address of and pass to the class.  Is the `m_callback` in `sensor->DoSomething(d1, d2, &m_callback);` a class member or a local?

Comment: I have two `m_callback` . Both are class members. One in the unmanaged project and the other in managed. `m_callback` in `sensor->DoSomething(d1, d2, &m_callback);` is just the reference to the class member  `m_callback` in my native code

Comment: any idea what is generating the following error? `An unhandled exception of type System.AccessViolationException occurred in .dll  Additional information: An attempt was made to read or write in the protected memory. This is an indication that other memory is corrupted.`